# Repeat wireshark commands

Tags: python

There are some wireshark .cap files. I need to split all these into 1 second time interval.
I was able to split .cap files using below editcap command.
Editcap -i time inputfile.cap outputfileprefix

Figure 1:Split files-output
But as there are many files I want to split; I have to use this command separately for each file name one by one. This takes time. Therefore, I thought of writing a code that will check for all the .cap files in a given folder and will split all the files.

For example, when I give the path as ‘/root/Desktop/Testcap/’ the program should split all the .cap within the subfolders (likepost, shortcomment) as well.
 The output (split files) should get the name of the input file as shown in Figure1.
This is what I wrote.
import os
path = '/root/Desktop/Testcap'
for dir_name, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(path):
     for filename in files:
          if filename.endswith('.cap'):
              **os.system('editcap -i 1 filename .....'**)
How to complete from the **bolded** part ? 
Thanks

Comment: `find /root/path/of/files -name "*.cap" -exec editcap -i {} outputfileprefix \;`

Comment: Thanks, I typed this command but nothing happens. I gave the time interval as   -exec editcap -i 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in python, but find and xargs are good tools to learn and use:

```
find /root/Desktop/Testcap -name ‘*.cap’ -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I % editcap -i % %
```

The print0 and -0 are to handle spaces in filenames.

Or, if you want to do it in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
startdir='.'
suffix='.cap'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
  for name in files:
    if name.endswith(suffix):
      filename=os.path.join(root,name)
      cmd = 'editcap -i 1 "{}" "{}"'.format(filename,filename)
      print(cmd)
      os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: `-print0 /xargs -0` really isn't needed here.  `-exec ... {} ...` does not subject the argument to word splitting.

Comment: William, that's true - I do find xargs more flexible in many cases, so it's a useful tool to have.  In this case I believe this is what Hasara would want using just find:
`find /root/Desktop/Testcap -name ‘*.cap’ -exec editcap -i 1 {} {} \;`

Comment: @dttocs In the above code of yours the split pcap files also gets written into the same folder as original files. Any chance we can write the split files to a separate folder and sub folders (same way as the original files are). Thanks